# Simple XOR ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation, xor, ruby-1.9.2

Apparently this used to work on ruby 1.8.7 but unfortunately not on 1.9.2

```
class String
  def xor(key)
    text = dup
    text.length.times {|n| text[n] ^= key[n.modulo key.size] }
    text
  end
end

def encode(_original, _pass = 'testvendor')
  _original.xor(_pass)
end

puts encode('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.')

#output=>    
8
EE
DEBDREBDEVSR
TTTT
TNZV0D
SE E    CRVSETENR   D

TT
    EKS0DSO VD
EVVTE S 
RSREXE+E T
 RR
T _TOEDE RO E
TTD
K
```

It returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `^' for "V":String
```

Any idea on how to get this working?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1.8, the [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method returned a Fixnum which was the byte at the specified index. In newer version, [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns a String because strings are made of characters and the character-to-byte mapping depends on the encoding. Looks like you're using a String as a byte buffer so you should be working in Array instead of String:

```
class Array
  def xor(key)
     a = dup
     a.length.times { |n| a[n] ^= key[n % key.size] }
     a
  end
end
```

And then to use it:

```
mangled_array = string.codepoints.to_a.xor(key.codepoints.to_a)
```

Then if you really want a String (which will contain a bunch of unprintable control characters and zero bytes and such things), then:

```
mangled_string = mangled_array.inject('') { |s,c| s << c }
```

And then to unpack:

```
mangled_string.
  codepoints.
  to_a.
  xor(key.codepoints.to_a).
  inject('') { |s,c| s << c }
```

All of this should maintain UTF-8 all the way through and that's what you want.

You could probably patch your `xor` into Enumerable and skip the `to_a` business if desired. You could probably also adapt this to patch for String as well.

You shouldn't be using String for byte buffers anymore, you're better off using arrays of Fixnum for that with explicit encoding handling.

Comment: thanks for the tip man, one thing tho: once calling the methods it returns `undefined method 'xor' for #<Enumerator:0x007fef79b04670>` then if I use `string.bytes.to_a` it says: `can't convert String into Integer` ?

Comment: @ludicco: Sorry about that, demo code and all. I added the `to_a` stuff. Presumably `key` was also a string and so needed `.bytes.to_a` as well.

Comment: mu is too short, I've just udpated the question with the output I used to get in 1.8.7 which is the output I like, by using your method it generates many lines containing only numbers, like `56, 10, 1, 17` instead. Is there any way to convert it back so I can obtain the same output? Thanks

Comment: I've added a bit more for you. Unicode complicates things a little bit but it has to be done.

Comment: that worked pretty well man, thanks a lot...seems far more complex, I wouldn't have a clue on how to build this ;) cheers

Comment: @ludicco: You could also go with `str.bytes` instead of `str.codepoints`.

Answer (score 1):

Call `#ord` and `#chr` methods to convert from character to it's number representation and back to character

So your example should call:

```
text.length.times {|n| text[n] = (text[n].ord ^ key[n.modulo key.size].ord).chr }
```

Comment: Sorry, I get this: `NoMethodError: undefined method ‘module’ for 0:Fixnum` ?

Comment: If you compare his code to yours, you should be able to find the typo by yourself :)