# Little Perl XOR decode script porting to Ruby

Tags: ruby, perl

I have a little Perl code (simple XOR decryption) and I want to port it to Ruby to add it to another script but I'm really lost with XOR encoding/decoding in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# XOR password decoder
# Greets: Joni Salonen @ stackoverflow.com

$key = pack("H*","3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cd");

print "Enter string to decode: ";
$str=<STDIN>;chomp $str; $str =~ s/\\//g;
$dec = decode($str);
print "Decoded string value: $dec\n";

sub decode{ #Sub to decode
    @subvar=@_;
    my $sqlstr = $subvar[0];
    $cipher = unpack("u", $sqlstr);
    $plain = $cipher^$key;
    return substr($plain, 0, length($cipher));
}
```

Example of use with perl:

```
$ perl cf6deca.pl
Enter string to decode: )4-H5GX\:&G\!6
Decoded string value: likearock
```

Thanks for any help and time.

I want something like this in Ruby:

```
key = ['3cb37efae7f4f376ebbd76cd'].pack('H*')

print "Enter string to decode: "
STDOUT.flush
a_string = gets
a_string.chomp!
a_string = a_string.gsub(/\//, "")
dec = decode(a_string)
puts "Decoded string value: "+dec

def decode(in)
        cipher = in.unpack('u')
        plain = cipher^key;
        plain.slice(len(cipher))
        return plain
end
```

I know is TOTAL MESS, please help :)

Comment: Show us code to let us see how far you got in your attempt. What went wrong or what are you having difficulty with in your attempt? Many of the Perl functions have Ruby equivalents, once you allow for the difference in the languages' syntax.

Comment: I mean I can't find anywhere how to decrypt an encrypted string with XOR and a key under Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at some of the questions here on stackoverflow, it appears that ruby may not have bitwise string operators.  [One post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267548/simple-xor-ruby-1-9-2) suggests this may work to provide such an operator:

```
class String
  def xor(key)
    text = dup
    text.length.times {|n| text[n] = (text[n].ord ^ key[n.modulo key.size].ord).chr }
    text
  end
end
```

Comment: Any help on my pseudo-Ruby script? :)

Comment: @xtmtrx: sorry, I've been and will be busy.  My answer was intended to work with strings, so you don't need the unpack, but you should put the key into a string, not an array.  If you've had no luck by then, I'll try to come up with an example in a couple days.

Comment: thanks, I'll keep trying but waiting for you with an example or maybe "re-make" of my lame try above, when you have time no worries.